# How to show file upload button once in a nested form in rails 4?

Tags: file-upload, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, nested-forms

I have a parent (playlist) -> child (tracks) structure in my rails app.

What I am doing in the form is showing attributes from the parent and then I have a table for the child attributes.

```
 <%= form_for(@playlist) do |f| %>
  <% if @playlist.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@playlist.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this playlist from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @playlist.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Playlist Name: " %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label " Image: " %>
    <%= f.file_field :photo %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="field">
  <h5> description: </h5>
  <br>
    <%= f.text_area :description, :size => "80x3"%>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <h5> Add some music: </h5>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.fields_for :tracks, Track.new do |ff| %>
      <%= ff.file_field :audio, :multiple => true %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <% if !@playlist.tracks.blank? %>
  <table id="tracks" class="display">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Delete</th>
          <th>Track</th>
          <th>Album</th>
          <th>Artist</th>
          <th>Label</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody>
    <%= f.fields_for :tracks do |ff| %>
      <%= render "track_fields", :f => ff %>
    <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Save" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I am using paperclip to upload the files.  I am uploading images on playlist model and mp3s on the tracks model.

The code in question is the following:

```
<div class="field">
        <%= f.fields_for :tracks, Track.new do |ff| %>
          <%= ff.file_field :audio, :multiple => true %>
        <% end %>
</div>
```

I feel this is a hack.  Why do I have to add a new track for me to show the file_field (choose file button) once?  Towards the bottom of the form, you will notice that I have to call

```
 <%= f.fields_for :tracks do |ff| %>
```

again because I want to iterate through all the tracks for the playlist and show them in a table.

Not sure if this question makes sense, but how do I show the file_field once (I feel Track.new is a hack and I think its messing up in saving the model)?

EDIT:
here is a screenshot of what happens if I don't have Track.new:

[image]

Comment: Just try with the normal `<%= f.fields_for :tracks do |ff| %>`.

Comment: that will create as many buttons (Choose file...) as there are tracks, which I don't want.

Comment: Could you post a picture of it?